# Angular 2 - Styling Component's selector border css property

Tags: angular, components

**Update:** In my comment bellow you can find a zipped project on Google drive. Can anyone make a Plunker (I have never done it - what needs to be changed, any article/blog explaining this change).

I have a `SearchComponent` which extends `BaseComponent` and I am passing `ElementRef` down to `BaseComponent` so that `BaseComponent` can add a border style to `SearchComponent`'s selector tag: `auction-search`.

Basically I want to draw a border for all components (that extend `BaseComponent`) on a page, so I can easily identify them.

However it seems that the width of `auction-search` tag is auto (I don't know if this is 0px based on the CSS box in the picture below.

Using Chrome Tools inspection window when I add a div element with the same content and style below auction-search element (as shown in the picture below), I can then see a proper border and a real width is displayed.

**So the question is how to give a component's selector a proper width so it can become a normal container like a DIV? Add position: absolute??**

I played with adding ...

```
style.border = '8px solid green';position:absolute
```

and I got the bounding border, however that affected the next div element which will have text overlapping the component's text.

I believe I cannot use host property of the base component because the decorator's properties are not inherited. Can someone confirm?

**What is the easiest way to propagate the same change in CSS e.g. throughout all components?**

```js
host: {
     'style': 'border: 8px solid green'
     }
```

Thanks,
Rad

**Here is the code for my 2 components:**

```js
//base-component.ts
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef} from "angular2/core";

@Component({selector: 'base-component'})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit 
{
  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef){
    _elementRef.nativeElement.style.border = '4px solid green';
  }

  //auction-search.ts   
  import {Component, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
  import {BaseComponent} from "../base/base-component";

  @Component({
    selector: 'auction-search',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/search/search.html'
  })
  export default class SearchComponent extends BaseComponent
  {
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef)
    {
      super(_elementRef);
    }
  }
```

app/components/search/search.html

```html
<p>
  Some text with <br>
  Another line
</p>
```

app/components/application/application.html

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <auction-search></auction-search>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: please provide plunker.

Comment: @micronyks I have never done it. Can you help me convert this zipped project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1I1nQTGClv3ZTFoOHhZTmwtajQ/view?usp=sharing to Plunker's equivalent.  That will really help me in the future. Thanks.

Comment: look this and change it. made for you - http://plnkr.co/edit/BZKrEG4xSXzl5v881rol?p=preview

Comment: @ micronyks. How can I mark your answer as correct. Thank you. It is funny, I played some more with css properties that will give a non-existing html 4/5 tag, like Angular's component selector: <auction-search> a 'block' display style and come up with the same answer. See what needs to be done in the base class in the answer bellow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand your problem exactly but this might help you.

```
 host:{
    'style': 'display: block;', 
  }
```

***[Take a look here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BZKrEG4xSXzl5v881rol?p=preview)***

or

**UPDATE**:

As you want to apply styles through program only, I have made this

http://plnkr.co/edit/9LvtDq7xei0WEVzAelHv?p=preview

which uses `directive` concept of Angular2. With that I have used `ViewChild`,`exportAs`. In this example,my `BaseClass` has some child components(more than one child components). By using `directive` and `elementRef`, you can target individual child component as you want. 
Now you don't have to extent `Baseclass` as you did in your demo.

```
import {Directive,Component,ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {Directive,Component,ViewChild,ViewChildren,ElementRef,Renderer} from 'angular2/core';
import {SearchComponent} from 'app/searchComponent';
//import {MyCustomDirective} from 'app/directive';

@Directive({
  selector:'[my-custom-directive]',
  exportAs:'customdirective'
})
class MyCustomDirective{

  constructor(private _renderer:Renderer,private _el:ElementRef){

  }

 firstChildCmp(className:string,isAdd:boolean)
 {
     this._el.nativeElement.style.border = '2px solid orange';
 }
 secondChildCmp(className:string,isAdd:boolean)
 { 
   this._el.nativeElement.style.border = '2px solid red';
 }
 thirdChildCmp()
 { console.log('firstChildCmp');
     this._el.nativeElement.style.border = '2px solid blue';
 }
} 


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives:[MyCustomDirective,SearchComponent],
    template: `
    <div>
        <div >Some content here</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <auction-search #var1=customdirective my-custom-directive></auction-search>
      <auction-search #var2=customdirective my-custom-directive></auction-search>
      <auction-search #var3=customdirective my-custom-directive></auction-search>
  </div> 
    `,
    host:{
    'style': 'display: block;', 
  }
})
export class BaseComponent{
  @ViewChild('var1') firstElement;
  @ViewChild('var2') secondElement;
  @ViewChild('var3') thirdElement;

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef){
    _elementRef.nativeElement.style.border = '4px solid green';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.firstElement.firstChildCmp();
    this.secondElement.secondChildCmp();
    this.thirdElement.thirdChildCmp();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @micronyks. This works but it requires a complex setup. I clarified my question in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411386/angular-2-affecting-all-components-on-a-page-third-party-and-your-own-at-onc

Answer (score 4):

**Here is the solution for my case. @micronyks Thanks for stepping in.
I cannot use host property because it is not inheritable property.**

**I also wanted to know if there is an easier way to spread some style changes throughout all components without using inheritence?. So basically I want to avoid changing the signature of component's class declaration.**

//base-component.ts

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'base-component'
    /* This won't work - no inheritance of component decorator properties (Am I right here?)
    ,
    host: {
        'style': 'display:block'
    }
    */
})
export class BaseComponent {
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef,  renderer: Renderer)
    {
        //first way
        renderer.setElementStyle(elementRef.nativeElement, 'border', '1px solid blue');
        renderer.setElementStyle(elementRef.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');

        //second way
        //elementRef.nativeElement.style.border = '1px solid blue'
        //elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'block'
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check my updated answer. without extending baseclass , if you want to get reference of child component, you can use `directive` and `exportAs` as shown in my answer.