# Angular 2 - Affecting all components on a page (third party and your own) at once

Tags: typescript, angular

I already asked [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367340/angular-2-styling-components-selector-border-css-property), but I wanted to clarify it here and to see if there is an easier way to achieve the effect I wanted shown in the picture bellow.

If I have several components on a page (some of them might have child components), I want to add a border to all o them (possibly changing color randomly) and to add the name of the component (or the name of its selector) to to upper right corner of the component's box. 
This way I want to easily identify the components layout on my page.

I have 2 questions:

**1. What is the easiest way to achieve this if your page has some yours and some third party components.**

**2.What would be the easiest way to achieve this just for your own components?**

**Note: I would like to have the least intrusive way to achieve this and it would be desired to show/hide the borders and Component names with a global variable which would be triggered for debugging purpose**

**This is the effect I want to accomplish:** 
[image]

**Update: I am adding 2 screenshots**

**Application components**
[image: Application screenshot]

**Batarangle 2 view of the application**
[image: Batarangle screenshot]

Comment: This isn't quite a solution, but it's all the time I have for now. Sadly you can't use css to select the attributes because angular2 generates random attributes for it. You can however use javascript to determine what elements have an attribute starting with _nghost. I made a small script with vanilla js here. I hope it helps. http://plnkr.co/edit/ptQjrhVrAUhia1EBi0Jl?p=preview

Comment: do you want to do it programmatically or it would be fine to go with pure css(styleSheet)?

Comment: @micronyks css only is not really possible because there is no class or  attribute that is present on all components. Angular generates an _nghost-somethingrandom attribute but since part of it is random it can't be used. What I did is to search for elements that have attributes starting with _nghost.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with. I only added border. 
If anyone has a shorter solution let me know.

Basically I created a directive that will add border style to any component that is extended with directive "componentcolor" with the default color of blue which can be changed when directive is declared.

Each component that has any child components needs to add:
directives: [ComponentVisualizerDirective]

This is very intrusive, as my previous solution that is possible by inheriting a base component class.

componentvisualizer.ts

```js
import {Directive,ElementRef,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector:'[componentcolor]',
    properties: [
        'color: componentcolor'
    ]
})
export class ComponentVisualizerDirective implements OnInit
{
    private color: string = 'blue';
    constructor(private _el:ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit():void {
        this._el.nativeElement.style.border = '1px solid ' + this.color;
        this._el.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    }

}
```

application.html

```html
<auction-navbar component></auction-navbar>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Left column contains only search form the style col-md-3 comes from
        Twitter Bootstrap grid system-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <auction-search component="green"></auction-search>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

application.ts

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import NavbarComponent from "../navbar/navbar";
import SearchComponent from "../search/search";
import {ComponentVisualizerDirective} from "../../directives/componentvisualizer";

@Component({
    selector: 'auction-application',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/application/application.html',
    directives: [
        NavbarComponent,
        SearchComponent,
        ComponentVisualizerDirective]
})
export default class ApplicationComponent {
}
```

Comment: that's a nice and elegant solution but I think it has one flaw, it will not cover third party components that are not directly included in your code. :(

Answer (score 1):

A less pretty way of doing it would be to just search for elements with an attribute starting with **_nghost**.

It's less elegant than the directive solution and if angular2 decides to no longer use that attribute it would break but it covers the case of components not directly used in your code (third party components importing other thirdparty components).

I made a service that will let you access all component elements found in the document body.

```js
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class ComponentDecorationService {

    public forAllComponents(action: (e: HTMLElement) => void) {

        this.highlight(document.body, action);
    }

    private highlight(element: HTMLElement | Element, action: (e: Element) => void) {

        if (element.attributes) {
            for (var j = 0; j < element.attributes.length; j++) {
                if (element.attributes.item(j).name.startsWith("_nghost")) {
                    action(element);
                }
            }
        }

        if (element instanceof HTMLElement && element.children) {
            for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
                this.highlight(element.children[i], action);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```js
export class App {

  constructor(private ComponentDecorationService: ComponentDecorationService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.ComponentDecorationService.forAllComponents((e) => {
      e.classList.add('highlighted-component');
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @toskv. I will try this. But when I inspect the source in Chrome dev tools I cannot find any attributes starting with _nghost. Can you check this project: https://github.com/AlexanderTyshchenko/AngularJSAuction.git This is what I used in the screenshots above. I will take a look at Batarangle Chrome extension to see how do they come up with components tree.

Comment: @Rad it looks like I was mistaken in thinking that attribute is there for all ocmponents. I was using ng-angular and the components generated by it always have the styleUrl property always set. That however will not always be the case, thus my answer is incomplete (I'll edit it to show that). Batarangle seems like a good way to go. :)

Comment: A regular expression like this: <([a-z-]+-[a-z-]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*)</\1>|\s+/>) will find all elements on the page that have "-" dash in it. Like <auction-navbar> etc. I am not sure if there is any Angular 2 property that can be used on a Component/Directive to identify it as such.

Comment: @Rad components are not required to have a - in their name, are they?

Comment: no, but if I use this convention I can at least provide a way to find my components. Did you check Batarangle project. I didnt

Comment: Check my answer bellow. I think this is the closest answer I came up with. There is a reflection API in Angular located here: \node_modules\angular2\src\core\reflection\reflector.d.ts

Comment: See: https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular2/2.0.0- beta.7/angular2.core/ComponentMetadata-class.html and https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular2/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.core/DirectiveMetadata-class.html. The array componentsanddirectives will be filled with "selector" property of annotation object of type ComponentMetadata or DirectiveMetadata. "directives" collection will contain both components and directives.

Comment: I don't know how to check if some object is of type "DirectiveMetadata". When I check "typeof annotation" it is just "object". In console if I enter annotation and press enter it shows underneath ComponentMetadata object data. If I figure out the type I could filter out directives. I would prefer this way, otherwise these 2 types have some different properties. ComponentMedatata has moduleId property and I can check for the existence of this property. Once all components are found one can find the elements by tag and style it as wish.

Comment: I added the picture to show available properties of ComponentMetadata and DirectiveMetadata

Answer (score 0):

You can highjack (monkey patch e.g. https://davidwalsh.name/monkey-patching) `@Component` and then you get the modify the component behavior as you like.

Comment: Thanks @basarat. Can you give me an example of how to do it in Angular 2? I added 2 new screenshots. I was wondering how Batarangle manages to find out the component tree. Can I get a hold of some root Angular 2 object that will contain parsed component tree and then I suppose I can get the "native element" of each that I could manipulate? 
I know their extension deals directly with chrome engine, but I believe they still use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**See my comments to toskv@ answer. I came with with this solution.
After running Show() method bellow: bellowcomponentsanddirectives array will contain this:**

["auction-application", "auction-carousel", "auction-footer", "auction-navbar", "auction-product-item", "auction-stars", "[component]", "auction-search", "[component]"]

Notice: [component] is the selector for a custom directive.
One thing I could not figure out (how to filter out directives) is:
annotation variable will either be of type: ComponentMetadata or DirectiveMetadata. type of annotation returns "object" while I see the proper type when I enter: annotation in Chrome Js console.

```js
export default class ApplicationComponent {
    componentsanddirectives: string[] = [];
    constructor(private _applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {}

    Show():void {
        let config = {};
        // a hack to get app element in shadow dom
        let appElement: ElementRef = this._applicationRef['_rootComponents'][0].location;


        this._applicationRef.componentTypes.forEach((component) => {
            let annotations = reflector.annotations(component);
            this.RecursiveCall(config, annotations);
        });
    }

    RecursiveCall(config:  {}, annotations: any )
    {
        annotations.forEach((annotation) => {
            this.componentsanddirectives.push(annotation.selector);
        });

        if (annotations[0].directives != undefined && annotations[0].directives.length > 0)
        {
            annotations[0].directives.forEach((component) => {
                let annotations = reflector.annotations(component);
                this.RecursiveCall(config, annotations);
            });

        }
    }
}
```

This picture shows what is in: annotation variable during recursion:
[image]